# Dataproc Zeppelin component hides the cell output after few minutes of starting while the spark job is still running

Tags: apache-zeppelin, google-cloud-dataproc

Dataproc Zeppelin component hides the cell output after few minutes of starting while the spark job is still running and there is no way to show it again. It appears only after the cell processing ends. For the first few minutes the logs keep showing however it suddenly disappears saying outdated (which is not the case as the cell is still processing pyspark code). Has anyone encountered similar issue. Is there anything in the configuration that can be changed to fix this?